# reference as parameter in C

Tags: c, struct

This appears to be a simple problem but I haven't had any luck searching for any answers so here goes. I have a struct Person with char* name and int age. I have the following method:

```
void Person_messup(struct Person &who) {
    who.name="asdfasdf";
    who.age = 9001;
}
```

compiling this code gives me the following error:

```
error: expected ; , or ) before & token
```

I can implement the above just fine using pointers or even passing an object struct but I'm having trouble with this particular implementation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are no references in C. Perhaps you meant C++.

Comment: Well, just use `->` instead of `.` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no references in c - pass the struct as a pointer.

```
void Person_messup(Person *who) {
    who->name="asdfasdf"; // or really strcpy!
    who->age = 9001;
}
```

(or use c++ !)

Comment: oh man -_- thanks a lot for that. That's what I get for switching back and forth between the two;

Comment: @lululoo - I did have to check they hadn't been added in C11. Personally I avoid non-const refs in C++ it's too much like a side effect

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 'struct Person * who'.